# Subset data in and not in

Tags: python

Suppose I have this data:

```
dat = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

and I want to subset vector `a` from `begin` to `end` and vector `b` that does not include from `begin` to `end` that are values (not indexes).

```
begin = 4
end = 7
```

How would I accomplish this?

Desired output:

```
a = [ 4 5 6 7 ]
b = [ 1 2 3 8 9 10 ]
```

Comment: Are those `begin` and `end` values, or indexes? (It might help if your example list values weren't monotonically increasing integers that all look like indexes…)

Comment: @abarnert They are values, not indexes. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *think* you're intending those `begin` and `end` values to be values in the list, not indexes into it. (Although it would be a whole lot clearer if your values weren't monotonically increasing integers that look just like indexes…)

Otherwise, all you'd need is `dat[:begin] + dat[end:]` and `dat[begin:end]`, but those would be the wrong values for your example—you clearly don't want to start at position 4, but position 3 (which has value 4).

---

And I *think* you're expecting the values to be in sorted order, but that's kind of a wild guess.

If so, what you want to do is find the positions of `begin` and `end` in the list. You can do this by manually walking the list until you find them, but let's be clever and use the [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) library:

```
beginpos = bisect.bisect_left(dat, begin)
endpos = bisect.bisect_right(dat, end)
outside = dat[:beginpos] + dat[endpos:]
inside = dat[beginpos:endpos]
```

Notice that I used `bisect_left` on the left and `bisect_right` on the right, to make sure we get a half-open range (that is, the "stop" index is not part of the range) even though you specified the `begin` and `end` as a closed range (that is, 7 is supposed to be in the output, if it's present).

---

If they're *not* sorted, the question is ambiguous. There could be multiple ranges from 4-7 in the list. They could even overlap. So, you need to better specify the problem before you can solve it. But maybe you just want, say, all the values where `4 <= value <= 7`, without thinking in terms of ranges at all? That's easy:

```
outside = [value for value in dat if not 4 <= value <= 7]
inside = [value for value in dat if 4 <= value <= 7]
```

Comment: Good call on the overlap/non-distinct issues here, +1. I think the question is probably not specific enough for the general case, but hopefully one of us covered what the OP is after :P

Comment: @MattMessersmith I think between us we probably covered what the OP is after, and also anything anyone who manages to find this question in a search might be after… the only problem is whether they'll be able to figure out which question they were asking to find the right answer…

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use slice notation.

```
a = dat[begin-1:end]
b = dat[:begin-1] + dat[end:]
```

If you meant `begin` and `end` as data (where `begin` and `end` are distinct), then just find where the elements are first:

```
start_ind = dat.index(4)
stop_ind = dat.index(7)

a = dat[start_ind:stop_ind+1]
b = date[:start_ind] + dat[stop_ind+1:]
```

If your elements are sorted, use `bisect.bisect()` instead of `index()`. If you have duplicates/overlap, then you'll have to be more specific in the question.

Remember that the `[start:stop:step]` slice notation is NOT inclusive on `stop`.

Comment: I don't think this is what he's after. Although it's hard to be sure, with an ambiguous question.

Comment: Yeah, i think you're right. i saw your comment on the question. i've updated